# Why do the Progress Bar doesn't quit?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I have used an asyncTask to make an http request and hence i have used progress bar to indicate the progress of ongoings in that thread. Everything works fine till the `onPostexecute()` method is called, i have displayed the response string in the `Logcat` but my progress bar doesn't quit.

There was similar questions asked but i didn't get the required solution for the problem. 
Please help.

Here is my code:

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            prgDialog=new ProgressDialog(getActivity()); 
            prgDialog.setCancelable(true);
            prgDialog.show(getActivity(), null, "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            String responseString = null;
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    out.close();
                    responseString = out.toString();
                } else {
                    // Closes the connection.
                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Handle problems..
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Handle problems..
            }
            return responseString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.d("result", result);
                prgDialog.dismiss();
            // Do anything with response..
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try putting `prgDialog.dismiss();` before `super.onPostExecute()`?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure your onPostExecute() method is being called?

Comment: @joao2fast4u Yes i can see the response that i have received on the Logcat, to which i have included the code in on postExecute method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not calling `dismiss()` on the `ProgressDialog` instance you think(or want)you do. You create a `ProgressDialog` and assign it to the `prgDialog` reference only to call:

```
prgDialog.show(getActivity(), null, "Loading...");
```

which will create a **new** instance of `ProgressDialog` which you don't dismiss because `prgDialog` points to another not showing `ProgressDialog`. Try:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    prgDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, "Loading...");
}
```

This is why you should call static methods on the class and not some instance of that class.

Comment: yeah, now I know solution :D